# Informatica giving error while loading Teradata Number column

Tags: teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In a Teradata(13.5) target table we have column with data-type Number; when we try to load this table using Informatica flow it gives following error:

```
[Severity Timestamp Node Thread Message Code  Message
ERROR  4/1/2015 3:08:52 PM node01_<host_name>     WRITER_1_*_1 WRT_8229 Database errors occurred: 
FnName: Execute -- [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Illegal data conversion]
```

We have tried everything including: 
1. Changing Informatica target datatype to decimal, bigint, integer, varchar
2. Importing target table to Informatica using Informatica Target Designer but this Number field is imported as Varchar(0)
Please suggest how to solve this as changing target data-type is not an option for us.

Comment: My guess is it's some kind of ODBC issue. Have you tried googling on it? Can you try using JDBC instead?

Comment: Are you using pushdown optimizations? If you are, then can you share the query which Informatica is trying to push to Teradata?
Also, what is the source of loading? Is it a file with a Fastload or TPT connection or another database with ODBC or Teradata with full pushdown?

Comment: Thanks Maciejg, could you please tell how can I change the connector setting in Informatica from ODBC to JDBC.

Comment: Does not appear to be a TPT connection, unless you are using ODBC connector operator in TPT which isn't a fast approach from a file to Teradata. Generally in case of failure using these utilities, Informatica should say something like external loader failed etc etc.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, we're using just a simple ODBC load connecttion.

Answer (score 0):

You can import target table to Informatica using Informatica Target Designer, and then edit the datatype for the column to anything you want. It can be alterered without issues.

Comment: I have already done that but the problem is whatever be the change it always give me error for illegal data conversion.